# Density function from moment generating function

Tags: density-function, moment-generating-functions

I am trying to obtain a probability density function (PDF) from its moment generating function (MGF) and the problem is the nature of the MGF. My MGF is $M(t)=I_o^{\beta}(s)$, where $\beta$ is a positive integer:
\begin{equation}
M(t)=\left( \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} e^{t\cos \theta} d\theta \right)^{\beta}
\end{equation}

I am stuck in finding the PDF from $M(t)$, as this is not a standard form for which a look-up table type approach can be used.

I tried replacing $t$ by $it$ and then taking the inverse Fourier Transform route, but it didn't yield anything. Even if exact solution cannot be found, some sort of approximation or bound will also be helpful.

Comment: Is it in connection with the Von Mises distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution) ?

Comment: ...or non central $\chi^2$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) ?

Comment: No, its actually in connection with the Chebyshev chaotic maps.

Comment: Do we agree that $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function ?

Comment: Yes, for sure. I used the integral form of this function here instead of the name "zero-th order modified Bessel function of the first kind" just for the sake of clarity in my question.

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/925545

Comment: Thank you very much @JeanMarie, I will look into the link.